# Edge pixels repeated in texture mapped with fragment shader

Tags: three.js, glsl, fragment-shader

Im trying to replicate brush stroke with fragment shader. [here is my demo](http://cssing.org.ua/examples/brush/). See the stretched edges at the start of animation.

I have this setup with three.js:

```
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    uniforms: {
        time: { type: 'f', value: 0 },
        uvRate: {
            value: new THREE.Vector2(1,3.7) // aspect ratio of image
        },
        texture: {
            value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/stroke.png')
        },
    },
    vertexShader: vertex,
    fragmentShader: fragment
});

plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1,1, 1, 1 ),material);
```

Vertex shader to calculate aspect ratio:

```
uniform vec2 uvRate1;
void main() {
    vUv1 = uv - 0.5;
    vUv1 *= uvRate.xy;
    vUv1 += 0.5;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}`
```

And fragment shader with a little math to scale UVs for "brushing"

```
// math behind this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8qdmw3a91w
float scale1(float coord,float progress){
    coord = coord/progress;
    if(coord<0.88) {
        final = coord*progress;
    } else{
        final = pow( (3.*coord - 2.4),3.) + 0.75 + coord/8.;
        final *= progress;
    }
    return final;
}


void main() {
    float p = clamp(fract(time/20.) + 0.3, 0.,1.);  // 0.3 -> 1.0
    vec2 newuv = vUv1;
    newuv.x = scale1(vUv1.x,p);

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture,newuv);
}
```

But i get this kind of edge:

[image].

Does somebody know what's the reason behind this? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the texture wrapping since it is clamping to the edge by default. ( THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping )

try changing the texture's wrapS and wrapT properties after initialization, something like.

plane.material.uniforms.texture.wrapS = plane.material.uniforms.texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

Comment: Thank you for the idea! Tried that, unfortunately it didnt remove those edges =(

Comment: Another thing might be your modification of the "aspect ratio" in the vertex and fragment shaders... instead of modifying the aspect ratio in them, why not just use a scaling matrix to modify the plane? i.e. plane.scale = new THREE.Vector3(width,height,1); where width and height are values that you enter based on how much you'd like to scale the plane.

Comment: Here is how it looks without any aspect ratio calculations, [still effect present](https://imgur.com/a/KqndJAB)